# How to plot family tree in R

Tags: r

I've been searching around how to plot a family tree but couldn't find something i could reproduce. I've been looking in Hadley's book about ggplot but the same thing.

I want to plot a family tree having as a source a dataframe similar to this:

```
familyTree <- data.frame(
  id = 1:6,
  cnp = c("11", NA, "22", NA, NA, "33"),
  last_name = c("B", "B", "B", NA, NA, "M"),
  last_name_alyas = rep(c(NA, "M"), c(5L, 1L)),
  middle_name = rep(c("C", NA), c(1L, 5L)),
  first_name = c("Me", "P", "A", NA, NA, "S"),
  first_name_alyas = rep(c(NA, "F"), c(5L, 1L)),
  maiden_name = c(NA, NA, "M", NA, NA, NA),
  id_father = c(2L, 4L, 6L, NA, NA, 8L),
  id_mother = c(3L, 5L, 7L, NA, NA, 9L),
  birth_date = c("1986-01-01", "1963-01-01", "1964-01-01", NA, NA, "1936-01-01"),
  birth_place = c("City", "Village", "Village", NA, NA, "Village"),
  death_date = c("0000-00-00", NA, NA, NA, NA, "2007-12-23"),
  death_reason = rep(c(NA, "stroke"), c(5L, 1L)),
  nr_brothers = c(NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA),
  brothers_names = c(NA, "M", NA, NA, NA, NA),
  nr_sisters = c(1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 2L),
  sisters_names = c("A", NA, "E", NA, NA, NA),
  school = c(NA, "", "", NA, NA, ""),
  occupation = c(NA, "", "", NA, NA, ""),
  diseases = rep(NA_character_, 6L),
  comments = rep(NA_character_, 6L)
)
```

Is there any way I can plot a family tree with ggplot? If not, how can i plot it using another package.

The primary key is 'id' and you connect to other members of the family using "id_father" and "id_mother".

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know how to use R and its graphics? Have you looked at using igraph to represent your data and its graphics methods? A family tree is a type of graph, so igraph and the whole Graphical Models Task View would be a good place to start. Have you read that yet?

Comment: Perhaps you can modify plots in [ggphylo](https://github.com/gjuggler/ggphylo), an extension to ggplot2 to make phylogenetic tree plots.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As noted in the comments, you should try `igraph`. Here is a quick start:

```
require(igraph)
mothers=familyTree[,c('id','id_mother','first_name', 'last_name')]
fathers=familyTree[,c('id','id_father','first_name', 'last_name')]
mothers$name=paste(mothers$first_name,mothers$last_name)
fathers$name=paste(fathers$first_name,fathers$last_name)
names(mothers)=c('parent','id','first_name','last_name','name')
names(fathers)=c('parent','id','first_name','last_name','name')
links=rbind(mothers,fathers)
links=links[!is.na(links$id),]
g=graph.data.frame(links)
co=layout.reingold.tilford(g, flip.y=F)
plot(g,layout=co)
```

[image]

There aren't any names, and the arrows are going in the wrong direction, but you should be able to go from there.

Comment: Thanks nograpes. I looked over igraph but couldn't figure out where to start from. Your example is a good start.

Comment: I have another question. I managed to turn the tree 180 degrees and place the names instead of the numbers on the vertices. The problem is that the tree becomes too crowded. Is there any way i cam specify the layout to place more spaces between the vertices on the x axis?

Comment: To be honest I only learned of `igraph` a few days ago. They do have some nice documentation (http://igraph.sourceforge.net/) on their website, I'm sure it is possible.

Comment: i looked over the manual, but it looks to me that  layout.reingold.tilford() doesn't have any paramether for that

Comment: This sounds like a new question. You may want to check out other questions that are tagged [tag:igraph] as well.

Answer (score 9):

Have you tried the  `kinship2` package?

```
library(kinship2)
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4,5,6), sex = c(1,2,1,2,2,2), dadid = c(0,0,0,0,1,3), momid = c(0,0,0,0,2,4), famid = 1)
relation1 <- matrix(c(2,3,4,1), nrow = 1)
foo <- pedigree(id = df$id, dadid = df$dadid, momid = df$momid, sex = df$sex, relation = relation1, famid = df$famid)
ped <- foo['1']
plot(ped)
```

You can see the resulting plot:

[image]