# Plot a genealogy in R

Tags: r, plot, graph, igraph, genealogy

```
d = data.frame(
   offspring = c("G2I1", "G2I2", "G2I3", "G3I1", "G3I2", "G3I3", "G3I4", "G4I1", "G4I2", "G4I3", "G4I4", "G5I1", "G5I2", "G5I3"  ),
   parent1   = c("G1I1", "G1I2", "G1I1", "G2I1", "G2I3", "G2I1", "G2I3", "G3I2", "G3I2", "G3I1", "G3I4", "G4I3", "G4I3", "G4I1" ),
   parent2   = c("G1I3", "G1I2", "G1I2", "G2I2", "G2I2", "G2I2", "G2I3", "G3I4", "G3I1", "G3I2", "G3I4", "G4I1", "G4I1", "G4I2" )
)

print(d)

        offspring parent1 parent2
    1       G2I1    G1I1    G1I3  # generation 2
    2       G2I2    G1I2    G1I2  # generation 2
    3       G2I3    G1I1    G1I2  # generation 2
    4       G3I1    G2I1    G2I2  # generation 3
    5       G3I2    G2I3    G2I2  # generation 3
    6       G3I3    G2I1    G2I2  # generation 3
    7       G3I4    G2I3    G2I3  # generation 3
    8       G4I1    G3I2    G3I4  # generation 4
    9       G4I2    G3I2    G3I1  # generation 4
    10      G4I3    G3I1    G3I2  # generation 4
    11      G4I4    G3I4    G3I4  # generation 4
    12      G5I1    G4I3    G4I1  # generation 5
    13      G5I2    G4I3    G4I1  # generation 5
    14      G5I3    G4I1    G4I2  # generation 5
```

**Data representation**

This data represents a genealogy. Each line indicates an offspring and its two parents. I call them `parent1` and `parent2` because they are hermaphrodites. Also, they can clone themselves! Generations are non overlapping, meaning that all parents of offspring of the generation `n` were born in the generation `n-1`.

Let's consider an example. Individual `G3I4` was born in generation 3 (`G3`) and is the individual index 4 of this generation (`I4`; the index is just an ID). This individual is parent of individual `G4I1` and of individual `G4I4`. In fact, `G3I4` is the only parent of `G4I4` as she cloned herself.

**Question**

How can I graph this genealogy in `R`?

**Related post**

The post [How to plot family tree in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11280343/how-to-plot-family-tree-in-r) is very related but I failed to apply it to my data. The first question uses `igraph` which I am not very familiar with. But I failed to get anything good looking

```
d = tibble(
       offspring = c("G2I1", "G2I2", "G2I3", "G3I1", "G3I2", "G3I3", "G3I4", "G4I1", "G4I2", "G4I3", "G4I4", "G5I1", "G5I2", "G5I3"  ),
       parent1   = c("G1I1", "G1I2", "G1I1", "G2I1", "G2I3", "G2I1", "G2I3", "G3I2", "G3I2", "G3I1", "G3I4", "G4I3", "G4I3", "G4I1" ),
       parent2   = c("G1I3", "G1I2", "G1I2", "G2I2", "G2I2", "G2I2", "G2I3", "G3I4", "G3I1", "G3I2", "G3I4", "G4I1", "G4I1", "G4I2" )
    )

d2 = data.frame(from=c(d$parent1,d$parent2), to=rep(d$offspring,2))
g=graph_from_data_frame(d2)
co=layout.reingold.tilford(g, flip.y=T)
plot(g,layout=co)
```

[image]

but some individuals that don't leave any offspring are missing from the graph.

The second answer uses `kinship2`. To my understanding, `kinship2` can't deal with asexual reproduction.

Comment: Whats wrong with this graph? What is your expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing I see wrong is the overlapping nodes in G1. With more information I am happy to tweak the output as necessary.

```
library(igraph)
d = data.frame(
  offspring = c("G2I1", "G2I2", "G2I3", "G3I1", "G3I2", "G3I3", "G3I4", "G4I1", "G4I2", "G4I3", "G4I4", "G5I1", "G5I2", "G5I3"  ),
  parent1   = c("G1I1", "G1I2", "G1I1", "G2I1", "G2I3", "G2I1", "G2I3", "G3I2", "G3I2", "G3I1", "G3I4", "G4I3", "G4I3", "G4I1" ),
  parent2   = c("G1I3", "G1I2", "G1I2", "G2I2", "G2I2", "G2I2", "G2I3", "G3I4", "G3I1", "G3I2", "G3I4", "G4I1", "G4I1", "G4I2" ),
  stringsAsFactors = F
)

d2 = data.frame(from=c(d$parent1,d$parent2), to=rep(d$offspring,2))
g=graph_from_data_frame(d2)
#co=layout.reingold.tilford(g, flip.y=T)
co1 <- layout_as_tree(g, root = which(grepl("G1", V(g)$name)))
#plot(g,layout=co, edge.arrow.size=0.5)
plot(g,layout=co1, edge.arrow.size=0.25)
```

[image]